# Shall I have special domain server for Ubuntu users?

Tags: active-directory, ubuntu-16.04, active-directory-group

We've one ADDS server for 25 windows users.
Now we want to have **10 more Ubuntu machines** for our developers.
So is right to add those 10 Ubuntu users to the same ADDS or we should build some other server specially for Ubuntu/Linux users ?﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've shared there's no reason to have a separate forest. Just add the 10 Ubuntu machines to your existing domain. At that scale the out of the box AD integration should be just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, but one more doubt I've. Shall I allow the linux users who are added to AD to login win10 clients, or doing so will be not appropriate ?

Comment: They'll have to be created as users in AD to sign-in to the Ubuntu hosts. Whether you permit them to sign-in to your Windows hosts is a policy decision you'll have to make.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're really helpful. but what about the policy implementation, for Linux users how can I push policy like blocking USB, providing permissions, etc ?

Comment: You'd need a third party product to do that. Centrify, BeyondTrust and Quest all have tools in this space.

Comment: great Brian, you just cleared all my doubts..Thank you thank you so much..